# PHP Finding the value between two nth occurences of a string

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a comma separated string, and I need the PHP to find the value between the 12th and 13th occurrence of the comma in the string so I can make it into a variable. How would I accomplish this? The value is not necessarily the same amount of characters at any given time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method:

```
$csvString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15";
$desiredValueNum = 12;
$explodedArray = explode("," , $csvString);
echo $explodedArray[$desiredValueNum];  // Prints 13, which is between the 12&13th comma
```

Change 12 to whatever low index you want to find (remember, arrays start from 0)